# I need to understand below smart contract code

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

Can you help me explain below smart contract code I found on tomb finance, `tomb.sol` contract?

```js
// Initial distribution for the first 24h genesis pools
uint256 public constant INITIAL_GENESIS_POOL_DISTRIBUTION = 11000 ether;

// Initial distribution for the day 2-5 TOMB-WFTM LP -> TOMB pool
uint256 public constant INITIAL_TOMB_POOL_DISTRIBUTION = 140000 ether;

// Distribution for airdrops wallet
uint256 public constant INITIAL_AIRDROP_WALLET_DISTRIBUTION = 9000 ether;
```

- Why do they distribute ether for the pools?
- Why ether?
- Can they do that?
- What exactly is the value of 1 ether?
- If they had deployed this on BNB Chain, will this code will change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet alone doesn't distribute any ether, it only declares 3 constants. It's likely that there's some other functions in the code, that wasn't shared, that make use of these constants.

`ether` in this case is a Solidity [global unit](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/units-and-global-variables.html#ether-units). No matter on which network you deploy the contract, it multiplies the specified number by 10^18 (or 1000000000000000000). Current version of Solidity (0.8) is not able to store decimal numbers, so all native and ERC-20 balances are stored in the smallest units of the token. In case of native tokens (ETH on Ethereum, MATIC on Polygon, ...), that's wei. And 10^18 wei == 1 ETH (or 1 MATIC, etc - depending on the network).

If this code was deployed on other EVM network (such as Binance Smart Chain), the `ether` unit is the same. It doesn't work with ETH tokens, it "just" multiplies the number.